# How to align text next to an image in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

I want to align text so it would be next to the picture but on the middle of it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a Table, then insert the image in one cell, and type text in the cell next to it, then use text alignment for the cell in any way you wish.

***LibreOffice**: Select text, then Menu:Format>Align>Center (vertically)*

Comment: Same procedure in Word. Look to the (Table) Layout tab.